# Exclusion Script more than one DE

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, exclusion-script

I have a question about using exclusion script. How should you write it if you are trying to exclude 2 data extensions? I can't find examples of this anywhere. Below is what I came up with:

```
ROWCOUNT(LOOKUPROWS("Data_Extension1","email_field", EMAILADDR))>0
OR
ROWCOUNT(LOOKUPROWS("Data_Extension2","email_field", EMAILADDR))>0
```

Cheers!

Comment: Hey Joshua, Your code looks syntactically correct; can you confirm if the code you've shared works?

Answer (score 2):

The syntax of your script is correct - I suggest using the following workaround for exclusion scripts that are more than just one line:

In Email Studio, create an HTML Content Block and include your script in an AMPscript block:

```
%%[
set @rc = ROWCOUNT(LOOKUPROWS("Data_Extension1","email_field", EMAILADDR))>0
OR
ROWCOUNT(LOOKUPROWS("Data_Extension2","email_field", EMAILADDR))>0
]%%
%%=v(@rc)=%%
```

The above will evaluate to 1 if subscriber's email is included in one of the two Data Extensions and 0 if it's not. In your exclusion script, [call the Content Block](https://ampscript.guide/contentblockbyid/). It still needs to evaluate to `true` or `false`, so you can add the following logic:

```
TreatAsContent(ContentBlockById(ID_OF_CONTENTBLOCK)) == 1
```

Now if the email exists in one of the two data extensions, above will evaluate to `true` and send will be suppressed.